# accessing spreadsheet by ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google Apps script.
I need to access some information in the spreadsheet.
I navigate to the file and find its ID.
However, the function 
**var fileID = file.getId()**
var activityName = **Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get (fileID,'B1:B4');** doesn't seem to accept the ID, even thought the ID is correct as I logged it and checked.

```
function getTheInformation() {

  //navigate to the correct folder
  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var folderIter = dApp.getFoldersByName("scriptFolder");
  var folder = folderIter.next();

  //reality check
  Logger.log(folder);

  var filesIter = folder.getFiles();
  var i = 1;

  //cycle through the files
  while (filesIter.hasNext())
  {
    var file = filesIter.next();
    var fileID = file.getId()
    var fileName = file.getName();

    //here the code breaks
    var activityName = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get (fileID,'B1:B4');

    i++;
    Logger.log(fileName + " file ID " + fileID);

  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
function getTheInformation() {
  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var folderIter = dApp.getFoldersByName("Questions");
  var folder = folderIter.next();  
  var filesIter = folder.getFiles();
  while (filesIter.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesIter.next();
    var fileID = file.getId()
    var fileName = file.getName();
    if(fileName=='StackOverflow1') {
      var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get (fileID,'Sheet1!B1:B4')     
      Logger.log(values);
    }
  }
}
```

Things I did a little different: I added the sheet name to the range and I also checked for the correct file name.

Comment: Still won't work for me. "API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.get failed with error: Requested entity was not found. (line 31, file "Code")" What troubles me is that if I get the ID from the logger and put it manually everything works perfectly.

Comment: I can't fix what's not broke.

Comment: I tried your code, it never gets inside the "if" that's why it doesn't show the problem. If I comment out the "if" it shows the same problem.

Comment: 19-11-24 20:54:45:942 MSK] file:  ss1 
[19-11-24 20:54:45:942 MSK] fileID:  1nQ2ev74swQptKdui3DqA5S8wqRt6NO13GTWGJDjSUmY
[19-11-24 20:54:45:943 MSK] fileName:  ss1 
For some strange reason if (fileName == 'ss1') returns nothing.

Comment: Well did you change the `fileName` to your file name. Or did you change the Folder Name.  My drive is different than your drive.

Comment: Yes, sure, commented above.

Comment: Well clearly it's not your file.  Do you have spaces in the filename?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202982/discussion-between-cooper-and--).